# Numpy array adds extra list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a function that annotates some genomic variants with multiple items (detail snot important). For every variant, it stores all the information in a list. All variant lists are  added to a list which ultimately looks something like this:

```
[['chr9', 11849076, 'chr9', 12028629, 'DEL', 0, 179553, 0, 0, '', '', 
0, '', 0, 0, 13, 13], ['chr3', 5577129, 'chr3', 5708227, 'DUP', 0, 
131098, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 0, 0, 13, 13],...]
```

This big list is returned by the annotator function and then I would like to convert it to a numpy array which goes fine:

```
annotated_tn = np.array(annotated_tn, dtype="object")
```

However, the result is not as expected:

```
array([list(['chr9', 11849076, 'chr9', 12028629, 'DEL', 0, 179553, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 0, 0, 13, 13]),
       list(['chr3', 5577129, 'chr3', 5708227, 'DUP', 0, 131098, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 0, 0, 13, 13]),... ],dtype=object)
```

For some reason it adds an extra list() to all the lists in the array making them not indexable:

```
annotated_tn[:,1]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I believe the output should like this:

```
array([['chr9', 11849076, 'chr9', 12028629, 'DEL', 0, 179553, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 0, 0, 13, 13], ['chr3', 5577129, 'chr3', 5708227, 'DUP', 0, 131098, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 0, 0, 13, 13],..], dtype=object)
```

Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that there's a row in your data that doesn't have the same number of columns as the other rows.

If they were all the same length, then you're right and your code should work. But as soon as you add a row with a different length you get the exact result you're getting

Since you're only posting 2 rows of your data and both have 17 columns, then I can't say this for sure. But I'm pretty sure this is your problem

Comment: This was indeed the case for one of the 127 entries... Completely looked over that. Now the arrays are as they should